# ASI request app with access token best practice, design pattern

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest, access-token

I work with an app that interacts with the server on every screen.
I do not know before making the request if my token has expired, so sometimes they end up being rejected. In the meantime other requests are run, and they end up being rejected also. So the whole thing can collapse.I mostly use ASI request. What can I do to control them in a designed fashion? Should I create a singleton?

Thanks!